# Algebraic field extension

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let
$$F \subseteq K=F(A)$$
be an algebraic field extension, where $A$ is a subset of $K \setminus F$, for any $\beta \in F(A)$, show that there exists finitely many elements $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n$ in $A$, s.t. $$\beta \in F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n) \; .$$

I have no idea about this question.

Comment: Do you know the definitions of the notations $F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ and (in particular) of $F(A)$? If not, that's the place to start.

Comment: I know this, for a subset $S$ of K, $F(S)$ is the smallest field containing both $F$ and $S$.  Your comment gave me some idea, maybe I need to try to prove $F(A)$ is the union of all $F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n), \; \alpha_i \in A, \; n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show
$$
F(A) = \bigcup_{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n \, \in A, n\in \mathbb{N}} F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n) \; .
$$
It is easy to check that
$$
\bigcup_{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n \, \in A, n\in \mathbb{N}} F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n) 
$$
is a field containing $F$ and $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$, and
$$
  \bigcup_{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n \, \in A, n\in \mathbb{N}} F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)  \subseteq F(A) \; ,
$$
since $F(A)$ is the smallest field containing $F$ and $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$, then we obtain the equation.